# IE doesnt add HTML to the dom using $.append or $.html()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have a div that I'm trying to add html to. When I use a small html string it works, but when I try to add large html string nothing happens.

```
$("div") .html (data ) // about 1kB of html content 
$("div" ) .html() // it return empty
```

If I do the same with a little html code like `<p></p>` it works. Any suggestions?

I am using Internet Explorer 8, it works just fine in other browsers

Comment: What is the document's doctype? Is inserted HTML valid?

Answer (score 2):

- How many divs are there?
- Is `data` defined? If so what is it?
- Does `$('div').html('test')` populate the divs?
- Did you validate the huge block of html?
- Did you escape the newlines?
- Do any errors/exceptions get thrown? ( Firebug/Console )

If you get something like `unterminated string literal` then you just need to escape the newlines with `\`. You can also try making the variable and shorten it and see if jQuery fails at parsing it or not.

```
var longString = "\
<p>text</p>\
";

$('div').html(longString);
```

Comment: it is one div , and the data is an htmltext got from html editor 
when I read it by watch I can see the data

Comment: every thing wrok fine with little data but not with some thing bigger I think broken tags is the problem but why other browsers can handle it

Comment: Please provide the large data/html.

Comment: @evan, if it's broken HTML then the browser is under no obligation to do anything in particular with it. Different browsers definitely react differently to bad markup.

Comment: yeah all browsers can handle that except IE , I don't know why they not start from ground developing this browser